# double quote character as " (\textquotedbl) instead of ” (\textquotecblright)

Tags: luatex, ligatures

In my document there are double quote characters (`"`). Instead to typeset exactly `"` (in Latex `\textquotedbl`) I obtain right double quote character (in Latex `''` or `\textquotedblright`). Why does LaTex typeset

```
"Blablabla"
```

as “Blablabla” instead of "Blablabla"?

When I want “Blablabla” I type ``Blablabla'', so why does `"` become `”`?

I'm using LuaLatex and `fontspec`.

Answer (score 1):

`fontspec` applies by default `Ligatures=TeX` to the fonts defined for `\rmfamily` and `\sffamily`. These ligatures are supposed to reproduce the standard LaTeX settings.

You can disable it, but you'll lose all of them. Note that you have to declare a main font, because the default one is preloaded with `Ligatures=TeX` set.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily,\sffamily]{}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}

\begin{document}

"blabla"

``blabla''

“blabla”

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. Now I know that the problem is concerning ligatures. Fortunately the problem is for \ttfamily, thus I can activate TeX legatures for all excluding \tt text only.

Answer (score 0):

Use the character code for the desired character.

I use LuaLaTeX (which understands Unicode). The straight double quote is at hex character code 22. So, `^^^^0022` places it. I can do something similar for straight apostrophe: `^^^^0027`. These placed characters will not be affected by TeX ligatures.

In pdflatex, which does not understand Unicode, there is a similar method. But pre-Unicode is so old, I forgot it.

Also: Some TeX editors (including TeXWorks) may automatically make character substitutions, right there in the editor as you type. Beware!

You can try locally disabling ligatures using `fontspec`:

In Preamble (note that the braces are doubled):

```
\newcommand\nolig[1]{{\addfontfeature{Ligatures=ResetAll}#1}}
```

In document:

```
\nolig{text without ligatures '' and so forth}
```

Comment: Many thaks for your solutions. They are good, but the text is already typed by Authors and the search/replace is too long for all the text (it is a book of 1000 pages).